# How to insert tr.html() content before other tr tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the example -

```
tr = $('<tr>');
row = $('.addNewRow');
tr.html(utils.tmpl("row_tmpl", marginDetails)); //returning some html content
(tr.html()).insertBefore(row);
```

I want to insert the tr.html() content before the row. But when i am doing so it is throwing error "**TypeError: tr.html(...).insertBefore is not a function**". Please guide me with this.

Comment: just add the $ : $(tr.html()).insertBefore(row);

Answer (score 1):

As `tr` and `row` are already jQuery object. just use them

```
tr = $('<tr>');
row = $('.addNewRow');
tr.insertBefore(row);
```

Alternatively, You can also use [**.before()**](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```
row.before(tr)
```

Answer (score 0):

missed $ selector

```
 $(tr.html()).insertBefore(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing $ sign:

```
$(tr.html()).insertBefore(row);
```

But I this will be fine to do:

```
tr.insertBefore(row);
```

As tr contains the html() already.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing `$` which is causing this issue.

We can achieve your objective using somewhat simple code block also, corresponding JS fiddle is @ http://jsfiddle.net/ZVf48/5/, let me know if you need any clarification here.